# Can I resize UIScrollview contentSize property from rectangle to circle?

Tags: ios

I want to custom the scrollable area of `UIScrollview` from rectangle to circle. Is there any way to complete it? like resizing `contentSize`?

Comment: u mean make the scrollview become circle or just the touch scroll area?

Comment: Just touch scroll area

Comment: I didn't try this, but perhaps make the frame square, then set the scroll view layer's `cornerRadius` property to half the side of the square?

Comment: u can create an invisible view on top of the scrollview and use `CALayer` to remove a circular mask in it then it should give the effect that u wanted, more in [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512761/calayer-with-transparent-hole-in-it) or [this](http://atmarkplant.com/create-hole-in-uiview/)

Comment: thank you for your help~