# Cut transparent hole in the shape of UIImage into UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

I have an `UIView` in which I want to create a hole in the shape of the content of a `UIImageView`, but I can't get it to work. I can, however, mask an `UIView` to the shape of the `UIImage`.

My code:

```
let doorsMaskBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 111, height: 111)

// Background view
let doorsBgView = UIView(frame: doorsMaskBounds)
doorsBgView.center = navigationController.view.center
doorsBgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

vc.view.addSubview(doorsBgView)
vc.view.bringSubview(toFront: doorsBgView)

// Logo Mask
doorsBgView.layer.mask = CALayer()
doorsBgView.layer.mask?.contents = UIImage(named: "doors")!.cgImage
doorsBgView.layer.mask?.bounds = doorsMaskBounds
doorsBgView.layer.mask?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
doorsBgView.layer.mask?.position = CGPoint(x: doorsBgView.frame.width / 2, y: doorsBgView.frame.height / 2)
```

which results into:
[image: example]

I know how to *"cut"* a hole into a UIView in form of a shape I draw myself, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16518739/406677), I just can't seem to figure out how the get the shape of the `UIImage` and apply it as the cut.

Comment: A UIImage has exactly 1 shape: rectangular. Be more specific about what you mean. All not transparent areas? A color channel? Line detection?

Comment: The UIImage png file has as two channels, white and alpha channel. It should consider the white channel.

Comment: ok. BTW: did you set `masksToBounds`?

Comment: No, I did not since the contents of the image does not exceed the boundaries of the view and the `UIImage` scales the image, I did not expect I had to set it.

Comment: I am also not sure, if it is needed. I just saw a code fragment where it was used. Can you provide the image you use for masking?